# laravel request and response logging

Tags: logging, laravel

I am trying to catch an issue regarding a certain laravel response, so I am using the after filter to log all activity, but I cannot figure out how to dump request and response information to the log.

```
App::after(
    function ($request, $response) {
        Log::info('access.log', array('request' => $request->headers, 'response' => $response->headers));
    }
);
```

This code doesnt give out status code information for response, which I am mostly interested.

Is there a way to see what comes out on the final stage of passing information to web server? Something like this?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 22:35:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34-1+deb.sury.org~lucid+1
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
Expires: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 22:35:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Via: 1.1 localhost:8080
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 59

{"success":true,"result":{"min":5.7,"mean":9.7,"max":14.2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

While status code is finally returned in the headers, at this stage you won't find it in the $headers attribute. You can still get the status code by calling **$response->getStatusCode()**

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, I recently wanted to see all incoming requests and all outgoing responses in Laravel.

[This package](https://github.com/andersao/laravel-request-logger) supports both laravel 5 and 5.1, so I'm assuming you could also use it.

To install:

> Composer
>
> Add prettus/laravel-request-logger to the "require" section of your
>   composer.json file.
>
> ```
> "prettus/laravel-request-logger": "1.0.*" Run composer update to get the latest version of the package.
> ```
>
> or Run
>
> ```
> composer require prettus/laravel-request-logger
> ```
>
> direct in your terminal
>
> Laravel
>
> In your config/app.php add
>   'Prettus\RequestLogger\Providers\LoggerServiceProvider' to the end of
>   the providers array:
>
> ```
> 'providers' => array(
> ...,
> 'Prettus\RequestLogger\Providers\LoggerServiceProvider', ),
> ```
>
> **Publish Configuration**
>
> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Prettus\RequestLogger\Providers\LoggerServiceProvider" Configuration
> ```
>
> In your `config/request-logger.php` file, you can change configuration
>   for logger
>
> ```
> 'logger' => [
>
> 'enabled'   => true,
>
> 'handlers'  => ['Prettus\RequestLogger\Handler\HttpLoggerHandler'],
>
> 'file'      => storage_path("logs/http.log"),
>
> 'level'     => 'info',
>
> 'format'    => 'common' ]
> ```

**Examples:**

> {method} {full-url}
>
> [2015-04-03 00:00:00] local.INFO: GET
>   http://prettus.local/user/1?param=lorem ["REQUEST"] {method}
>   {full-url} {remote-addr} {port}
>
> [2015-04-03 00:00:00] local.INFO: GET
>   http://prettus.local/user/1?param=lorem 192.168.10.1 80 ["REQUEST"]
>   {method} {root} {url} {full-url} {path} {decoded-path} {remote-addr}
>   {format} {scheme} {port} {query-string}
>
> [2015-04-03 00:00:00] local.INFO: GET http://prettus.local
>   http://prettus.local/user/1 http://prettus.local/user/1?param=lorem
>   user/1 user/1 192.168.10.1 html http 80 param=lorem ["REQUEST"]
>   [{status}] HTTP:{http-version} {content}
>
> [2015-04-03 00:00:00] local.INFO: [200] HTTP:1.1
>   {"id":1,"name":"Anderson Andrade", "email":"contato@andersonandra.de"}
>   ["RESPONSE"]

Comment: I'd love to be corrected on this, however from what I could tell this provider only works with file logging. I was unable to get it working with the elasticsearch handler

Comment: Does this work with Laravel 4.1 ? I tried but failed. Can anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: Not sure, because at that time and in my post I mention 5 and 5.1. In the description on github it also only mentions versions 5 and 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Along with dumping request/response to log you can try [this service](http://apideveloper.io) to get nice UI.